#React why the page do not render?
if I use the following code, the page can work correct.
{videoRefs.current.map((videoRef, index) => ( (
          <div className='stream' key={videoRef.deviceId}>
            <video ref={videoRef.ref} autoPlay playsInline></video>
            <div className='overlay'><p>{devices[index]?.label || `鏡頭 ${index + 1}`}</p></div>
          </div>
        )))}

But when I add isVideoVisible[videoRef.deviceId], my video component will go wrong and just display the side bar
{videoRefs.current.map((videoRef, index) => ( isVideoVisible[videoRef.deviceId] && (
          <div className='stream' key={videoRef.deviceId}>
            <video ref={videoRef.ref} autoPlay playsInline></video>
            <div className='overlay'><p>{devices[index]?.label || `鏡頭 ${index + 1}`}</p></div>
          </div>
        )))}

import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';

function App() {
  const videoRefs = useRef([]); // 使用空數組來儲存 video 元素的引用
  const label = { inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'Switch demo' } };
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]); // 用於存儲設備列表
  const [streams, setStreams] = useState({}); // 存儲每個設備的流
  const [isVideoVisible, setIsVideoVisible] = useState({});


  // TODO: 處理開關變更事件，開啟一個鏡頭時，只能出現在一個視窗中，其他 conponent 需要關閉
  const handleSwitchChange = (deviceId, checked) => {
    if (checked) {

      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: { deviceId: deviceId }})
      .then(stream => {
        const videoRef = videoRefs.current.find(ref => ref.deviceId === deviceId);
        if (videoRef && videoRef.ref.current) {
          videoRef.ref.current.srcObject = stream; // 設置視頻流
          setStreams(prevStreams => ({
            ...prevStreams,
            [deviceId]: stream,
          }));
          setIsVideoVisible(prev => ({ ...prev, [deviceId]: true })); // 顯示視頻
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error('無法存取攝像頭:', err);
      });

    } else {
      if (streams[deviceId]) {
        console.log('關閉前的 stream:', streams);
        streams[deviceId].getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop()); // 停止流
        setStreams(prevStreams => {
          const newStreams = { ...prevStreams };
          delete newStreams[deviceId]; // 移除流
          return newStreams;
        });
        setIsVideoVisible(prev => ({ ...prev, [deviceId]: false })); // 隱藏視頻
        // 清除視頻元素的 srcObject
        const videoRef = videoRefs.current.find(ref => ref.deviceId === deviceId);
        if (videoRef && videoRef.ref.current) {
          videoRef.ref.current.srcObject = null; // 清除視頻元素的 srcObject
        }
      }
      console.log('關閉後剩餘的流:', streams);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
      .then(devices => {
        const videoDevices = devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'videoinput');
        setDevices(videoDevices); 
        console.log('找到的攝像頭:', videoDevices);

        // 初始化 videoRefs
        videoRefs.current = videoDevices.map(device => ({ deviceId: device.deviceId, ref: React.createRef() }));

        videoDevices.forEach(device => {
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: { deviceId: device.deviceId }
          }).then(stream => {
            const videoRef = videoRefs.current.find(ref => ref.deviceId === device.deviceId);
            console.log('videoRef',videoRef);

            handleSwitchChange(device.deviceId, true);
            
            if (videoRef && videoRef.ref.current) {
              videoRef.ref.current.srcObject = stream;
              setStreams(prevStreams => ({
                ...prevStreams,
                [device.deviceId]: stream,
              }));
          
            }
          }).catch(err => {
            console.error('無法存取攝像頭:', err);
          });
        });
        
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('無法取得媒體設備:', err);
        setLoading(false); // 如果出現錯誤，則停止加載
      });
  }, []); 


  return (
    <>
      <div className='sidebar'>
        <h2>LUXGroup</h2>
        {devices.map((device, index) => (
          <div key={device.deviceId}>
            {device.label || `鏡頭 ${index + 1}`} 
            <Switch
              {...label}
              defaultChecked
              onChange={(e) => handleSwitchChange(device.deviceId, e.target.checked)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className='stream-container'>
        {console.log('hihi')}
        {videoRefs.current.map((videoRef, index) => ( (
          <div className='stream' key={videoRef.deviceId}>
            <video ref={videoRef.ref} autoPlay playsInline></video>
            <div className='overlay'><p>{devices[index]?.label || `鏡頭 ${index + 1}`}</p></div>
          </div>
        )))}
          {/* isVideoVisible[videoRef.deviceId] */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

I expected that when I use isVideoVisible[videoRef.deviceId] ,I can handle the page component by the switch
